# For loop that outputs a boxed text

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm just starting with python...again.
Can you guys help me program a for loop that outputs this:

```
+-----+
|World|
+-----+
```

This is what I have so far...

```
name = '|World|'
for i in range(0,len(name)):
    print("-", end ='')
print ('\n', name)
for i in range(0,len(name)):
    print("-", end ='')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "Can you guys help me" is [not answerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) because it does not tell us **what you need to know**. "This is what I have so far..." Okay; **what happens** when you try this code? **How is it different** from the desired output? What do you think needs to happen in order to fix that? What specific help do you need with that?

Comment: Is it for practice or a part of a project where you can use a module?

Comment: @MSH - This is so rudimentary, no libraries are required.

Answer (score 2):

```
def print_boxed(s):
    fix = f'+{len(s)*"-"}+'
    print(f'{fix}\n|{s}|\n{fix}')


print_boxed('World')
print_boxed('Blablabla')
```

prints

```
+-----+
|World|
+-----+
+---------+
|Blablabla|
+---------+
```

Explanation: The function `print_boxed` takes a string `s` as an input, then creates the top and bottom part of the box called `fix` consisting of as many `-` as number of letters in `s`, enclosed by `+`. Then it encloses the string `s` first by `|` and then the resulting string again by newlines `\n` and finally by `fix`. The notation `f'{}'` allows for string formatting.

Answer (score -2):

On the first line, print a plus sign followed by a number of dashes equal to the length of the word followed by another plus sign.

On the second line, print a vertical bar followed by the word followed by another vertical bar.

On the third line, repeat the first line.

What is the difficulty?

Comment: This should be a comment instead. I agree that there isn't a clear question yet.

Comment: @JohnGordon: I've come to the conclusion that new programmers just can't see the patterns in data that more experienced programmers can. We find these things trivial. However, I don't know how to pass this intuition on to others.

Comment: @quamrana. Same way you got it: sit down and practice instead of trying to get someone else to do the work for you

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yes, that's the way I did it. However, there must be ways in this connected age where we can give new programmers a nudge.

Comment: @quamrana. I feel like this reliance on a nudge set up by the connection of our age is dulling their minds. The human brain learns by tedious repetition, not magic.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `"tedious repetition"`, true, true. - - (Darkness took me and I strayed away through thought and time.)

Comment: New Programmers are essentially aphasic. Just like with learning a new language - when you don't know it, it all sounds like gibberish. But, once you know a language, it's impossible for it to sound like gibberish ever again. How do you learn a language? Speaking it and receiving correction. How do you learn to program? Doing it and receiving correction.

Comment: @BeRT2me. Exactly. I've learned at least one new language as an adult, and I can tell you that there is no substitute for repetition and constantly forcing my brain to try to recall what I need. There is no magical nudge.

Comment: The best we can do it provide good quality correction. If you want great quality, personalized, and fast correction, be prepared to pay $ for it.